# A single user can login to multiple tenants with one email id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I am using ASPNETZERO multi-tenancy solution and I want to achieve following solution in that.

**My need is like One user share all details among all Tenants.**

**Let's say there is user1 registered in Tenant1 with email id, password and all fields.**

**Now what I want is this User1 can logged in any tenant using the same login details, I mean to say user1 can login in tenant2, tenant3 etc.. But without registering again and also with same login details.**

**Also user can edit details in any tenant and that need to updated in all tenants.**

Here is what I have planned :

> I am planning to put multiple entries of same user with different
> tenant id in default Usertables.  I mean to say, when user1 registere
> in tenant1 then I will copy all details of that user to all tenants.
> So I will create same user entry with tenant2 id, tenant3 id and so
> on..

I got it working by editing user-service file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of allowing a user to login to multiple tenants, the following approach can be used

- The user details should be generic and not under a tenant
- After adding user, you will assign the user roles for every tenant
- When the user logs-in, the data will be validated and then the user will be given a page to choose tenant for which he can work
- (OR), the user can provide the tenant name during login so that you can directly validate the user and allow to use the application
- Tenant level access will be based on the tenant and roles, if I have access to `Tenant1`, it means that i have a role for `Tenant1` and if I pass `Tenant2` to access, the system does not find any roles associated with my user for the `Tenant2`, denying access (401).

Comment: Thanks for reply..So you want to say like I just need to add tenant id & role id for users. And when user go to login user can select tenant and move ahead to login.

Comment: @Samif, yes you can do that or after user login, you show the list of tenants that he can access and allow him to choose

Comment: @Saravanan If we use the JWT token associated with the UserID and TenantID and generated upon successful login. When the switch happens should we do the logout and login or regenerate the token or even better way?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute as mentioned in point 1, you will have users at the global / provider tenant level, so no logout is required as you login and then choose the tenant. HTH